# JPA/Spring Queries on non-managed join tables

Tags: spring, jpa

I was wondering if the following is possible using JPA, Spring Repositories, or a combination of the two.

Say I have the following JPA managed entity:

```
+------------+
|notification|
+------------+
|id          |
|message     |
|isClosable  |
+------------+
```

Now say I have a simple join table that is NOT managed by JPA:

```
+------------------+
|user_notifications|
+------------------+
|id                |
|userName          |
|notificationId    |
+------------------+
```

I was wondering if something like this is possible:

```
@Query("FROM Notification n where n.id IN (select notificationId from user_notifications where userName = :user)")
getNotificationsForUser(String user);
```

Again, `Notification` is a managed `@Entity`, but user_notifications is not. Will I have to create a corresponding `@Entity` class to preform this operation.

+BONUS POINTS+

I would like individual users to close notifications, but again I am not sure how to interact with non-managed tables using JPA.

So I would like to have a spring repository method similar to:

```
@Query("DELETE from user_notifications where notificationId = :noteId AND userName = :user")
closeNotificationForUser(Long noteId, String user);
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: JPQL uses entities, their fields and associatins. Never tables and column names. If you need to query unmapped tables, then map them, or use SQL.

Comment: JPQL queries also start SELECT, DELETE or UPDATE. Anything else is non-standard vendor specific, and not worth using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @JB_Nizet's comment, I looked into using SQL with Spring Repository and found Spring's `@Query` annotation has a `nativeQuery` boolean property.

I was able to implement the select method as follows:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM notification WHERE id IN (SELECT notificationId FROM user_notifications WHERE userName = :user)", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Notification> findByUser(@Param(value = "user") String user);
```

Removing entries from the unmapped join table required creating a [custom repository method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations), the implementation of which is shown below:

```
// Required
@Transactional
public void closeNotification(Long notificationId, String user) {

    // note createNativeQuery
    Query query = entityManger
            .createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM user_notifications WHERE userName = :user AND notificationId = :notificationId");

    query.setParameter("notificationId", notificationId);
    query.setParameter("user", user);

    // executeUpdate(), not execute()
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```